# C/C++ any OS memory management API : hints to use swap

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, operating-system

I'm working on software using a library with a huge memory usage (e.g. LightGBM).

I'm working on a data-science software which as the property to reduce RAM usage dynamically when data is not asked, and reload it from disk when necessary depending on our needs, kind of an advanced and configurable swap to sum up.
Therefore, when I call external code, we except that memory follows kind of the same requirements.

When working on huge dataset, memory usage can go way further available memory, the idea his to limit memory usage to avoid being stuck at 100% memory usage.
As soon as I don't want to modify memory management within LightGBM's code because it would mean choose a specific version and re-adapt code each time I want to update. In my software, can I programmatically restrict (and later release) physical RAM usage of my application, to force swapping?

Excepted pseudo-code:

```
some_function_before();
some_API::please_use_swap(/*threshold=*/16);
some_process_with_heavily_memory_usage();
some_API::end_requirement();
some_function_after();
```

If there is another approach to resolve this, I'll pick it of course.

Thanks.

Comment: "My software as the property to reduce RAM usage dynamically..." Has it? Or are you trying to achieve that?

Comment: "kind of an advanced and configurable swap to sum up" Advanced how? Configurable how?

Comment: "As soon as I can't handle memory management of LightGBM ..." So at the specifc point of time when that happens..... ?

Comment: Is this a convoluted way of asking "Can I programmatically restrict (and later release) physical RAM useage of my application, to force swapping?". That is what I understand. But you also want to not change the applications code... I still am lost.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `any` is a C++ standard library header. So seeing `<any>` in the question title is a bit confusing (the question body makes no mention of it). So consider editing your title into something clearer.

Comment: Yes it has structures that handles automatic write on disk when necessary (depending on heuristics that I'm not aware of), "Can I programmatically restrict (and later release) physical RAM usage of my application, to force swapping?" is a good way to sum it up yes.

Comment: You can use [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) to assign a process to a job, and limit the job's working set size (physical memory usage). Not posting as an answer because I've never used it myself and don't have an example.

Comment: I find it optimistic that you think you can write software to optimize RAM usage, better than the OS writers can, when at the same time you have to ask this question how swapping works.

Comment: On POSIX systems, you can provide hints about usage of memory regions and file regions using `posix_madvise()` and `posix_fadvise()`. However, it seems that the `posix_madvise` advice value `POSIX_MADV_DONTNEED` is a no-op on Linux, so not that effective on Linux!

Comment: @MSalters: There are some cases where it wouldn't be hard to do better than the OS - e.g. pretching from swap before it's needed, saving to swap immediately after use when you know it won't be needed again for ages). Note that these cases exist for caches too (they're the reason lots of CPUs support  instructions for prefetching and flushing cache lines).

Answer (score 0):

There's such an API on Windows: `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`. You state how much physical RAM you want to use; the rest could be paged out.

As is normal, this is just a hint. Windows may decide that there's plenty of RAM and ignore your hint altogether.